# Are modern movies less saturated and darker in terms of lighting? What started this?

Tags: cinematography

I'm not sure if anyone else has noticed this or if it is nostalgia tugging but it seems to me that modern movies are much more darkly lit than, let's say, 80's movies.

Does anyone have anything to back up or anything that will prove me wrong? Does it have something to do with modern cameras instead of classic film?

An article i found claims that Spielberg is the cause. Does this hold up to scrutiny?
https://www.cracked.com/blog/the-annoying-visual-trick-all-films-are-doing-these-days/

Comment: I'm not sure I've got the energy to put up a full counter-argument to this; but let me just start with a frame challenge… What is that guy watching movies on? Fully-calibrated TV or even computer monitor? Unlikely. Most monitors out of the box are over-punchy, & even high-end TVs play a dangerous dance with the colour - gamut & contrast. His attempts to "correct" look like a children's cartoon, so I doubt he's seeing the images as intended.

Comment: [Side rant, I just paid several grand for a new OLED & so far have been able to correctly calibrate from my media computer playback, but they want another £150 from me to calibrate the *bloody awful* live TV picture. My old plasma, bless its soul, ran rings around it for accuracy].

Comment: I'd agree that in some genres vibrancy has been pulled back - but if you're going to watch movies all from the same genres, they're going to have similar look & feel. Watch Jumanji, Toy Story  or The Grinch if you want the full vibrancy hit.

Comment: Funny, some people have observed the opposite. It highly depends on the selection of films, example: If you watch war movies you cannot expect everything to look like candy. The linked blog article is biased, amateurish and mostly wrong. However, sometimes there are trends. Maybe it's worth a try to google for "color grading" trends.